# Null value returned from time to time by google geocoding API

Tags: api, geocoding, geocode

I have a problem with the google geocoding API.

Indeed, I am using coordinates (latitude and longitude) to find the city and the country. Because of this, I use this google geocoding API.

On the other hand, this is where I have a problem, sometimes it works but most often instead of recovering the city and the country I get NULL values.

I also checked in the Google API dashboard (where I saved the key number), and I see that a lot of calls go wrong: there is a 403 error. He passes, that's where I do not understand.

If I only take the URL directly in a browser, then I get the right values.
I do not understand why sometimes it works and other times (but more often) I get NULL.

here is the PHP code that I use:

```
$latitude = (isset($_GET["lat"])) ? $_GET["lat"] : NULL;
$longitude = (isset($_GET["long"])) ? $_GET["long"] : NULL;

if ($latitude && $longitude) {
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?       latlng=".$latitude.",".$longitude."&key=NUMCLE";
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
$jsondata = json_decode($data,true);
if(is_array($jsondata) && $jsondata['status'] == "OK")
{
    $city = $jsondata['results']['0']['address_components']['2']   ['long_name'];
    $country = $jsondata['results']['0']['address_components']['5']['long_name'];
    $street = $jsondata['results']['0']['address_components']['1']['long_name'];
?>
```

If you could help me with this problem it would be cool.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces from your URL?

Comment: Sorry but it's a bad copied paste, there is no space in the URL.

Comment: Even though it's technically classified as an error, `403` means **forbidden**. Which means there's no error in the code, but your request to get some resource is actively being blocked/refused because it doesn't meet some criteria. It might have to do with some account limits of using the service, it could be a lot of things, but it's not an unintentional error. You need to deal with the reason for which the `403` response is issued. Try to look deeper into the `403` and see if it holds any clues towards finding that reason.

Answer (score 0):

SSL/TLS is reqired for google web services.

Change

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?       latlng=".$latitude.",".$longitude."&key=NUMCLE";
```

to

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?       latlng=".$latitude.",".$longitude."&key=NUMCLE";
```